# Gif como background de uma activity

Tags: android

Sou novo na programação Android, e gostaria de adicionar um GIF como *background* de uma `Activity`. Tenho que fazer isto pelo Java ou consigo direto pelo XML? Não estou conseguindo *setar* a Gif.

Answer (score 1):

No Gradle adicione:

```
dependencies { 
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
}
```

Exemplo em sua Activity:

```
Glide.with(context).load("https://inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/glidepicasso/gifanimation2.gif") .into(idDoTeuImageView);
```

Caso seja da pasta drawable:

```
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.gifanimation2) // aqui é teu gif 
.asGif().into(gif);
```

Primeiro contexto de sua Class, segundo a url do Gif ou do drawable e terceiro teu ImageView que no caso é o id dele.

Link da lib: https://github.com/bumptech/glide